# PostgreSQL - Permission Denied when Importing CSV

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to pgSQL and I'm trying to import some data from a file called "github_data" for an assignment I'm working on. No matter what I've tried, I keep getting a permission denied error.  This is what I'm trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE github(
    topic VARCHAR(255),
    user_name VARCHAR(255),
    repo_name VARCHAR(255),
    repo_link VARCHAR(255),
    star_count INT);
    
COPY github 
FROM 'C:\Users\Public\MASTERS\database_management\importing_data' 
WITH (FORMAT CSV,HEADER);
```

The table was created with no issues, but I can't for the life of me get the CSV to import. When I run the query, I'm thrown this error:

ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\Public\MASTERS\database_management\importing_data" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501

This is what I HAVE tried:

- Added "Everyone" in file->properties->security and gave all permissions
- Tried running \COPY github FROM 'C:\Users\Public\MASTERS\database_management\importing_data' WITH (FORMAT CSV,HEADER); in SQL Shell (psql), same error
- Put the file in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin path (with Everyone and permissions)
- Put the file in the \tmp folder: C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\Masters\Sem3\database_management\pg_stat_tmp

I can't seem to find any other options. Any help is appreciated! The only thing I can think of is that I put it in the wrong \tmp folder.

Comment: the error message explains, you can put the file in an folder thaz every can read, or you check the security of the file and add postgres as user